# Pydantic validation. Check that a string does not contain certain characters

Tags: python, regex, pydantic

I need to make sure that the string does not contain Cyrillic characters. I check like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    content_en: str = Field(pattern=r"[^а-яА-Я]")


data = MyModel(content_en="Has wrong content 'йцукен'")
print(data)
>>> content_en="Has wrong content 'йцукен'"
```

But when I pass strings containing Cyrillic alphabet into the `content_en` field, an error is not raised.
Expected:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyModel
...
```

How to check correctly?
Python 3.8
Pydantic 2.5

Solution (thanks @chepner):

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    content_en: str = Field(pattern=r"^[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]*$")
```

Comment: Have you tried with the regex `'[^\u0400-\u04FF]'`?

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: Can you update your question with the validation data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches any string containing at least one non-Cyrillic character, not a string consisting *solely* of non-Cyrillic characters.

```
>>> MyModel(content_en="Has wrong content 'йцукен'")
MyModel(content_en="Has wrong content 'йцукен'")
>>> MyModel(content_en="йцукен")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/chepner/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 164, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyModel
content_en
  String should match pattern '[^а-яА-Я]' [type=string_pattern_mismatch, input_value='йцукен', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/string_pattern_mismatch
```

The correct pattern is `^[^а-яА-Я]*$`:

```
>>> class MyModel(BaseModel):
...     content_en: str = Field(pattern=r"^[^а-яА-Я]*$")
...
>>> MyModel(content_en="Has wrong content 'йцукен'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/chepner/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 164, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyModel
content_en
  String should match pattern '^[^а-яА-Я]*$' [type=string_pattern_mismatch, input_value="Has wrong content 'йцукен'", input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/string_pattern_mismatch
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^(?!.*[\u0401\u0451\u0410-\u044f]).+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rjtbT1/1).